# MergeSort Algorithm "IndexOutOfRangeException"

Tags: c#, sorting, mergesort

I've been reading the Introduction to Algorithms and tried to implement the pseudocode, but I can't seem to pinpoint what is causing `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

**Merge**

> The error happens at `left[i] < right[j]`

```
static void Merge(int[] array, int start, int middle, int end)
{
    i = 1;
    j = 1;

    for (k = start; k < end; k++)
    {
        if (left[i] < right[j])
        {
            array[k] = left[i];
            i = i + 1; // -> i++;
        }
        else
        {
            array[k] = right[j];
            j = j + 1; // -> j++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Solved**

> I solved it by setting all `i` and `j` variables to `0` and `k` to `k = start - 1`

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace? Have you tried debugging the application to see where you are trying to access an index out of range?

Comment: Please lookup guides on how to debug a C# application in the IDE (Visual Studio or whatever) you are using. I promise you it'll be worth your while.

Comment: Example for Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f) See also https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error in this line:

if (left[i] < right[j])

since ***i*** exceeds ***left*** array length when it becomes 6 and array ***left*** has only 6 elements.

It is very easy to figure it out when you use debugging.